# How to setup Grunt, Webpack and Babel

Tags: gruntjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

So, I'm wondering what the best practices are for integrating Babel and Webpack with Grunt. There is a [grunt-babel plugin](https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel), a [grunt-webpack](https://github.com/webpack/grunt-webpack) plugin and a [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) for Webpack. Should one configure Babel in Webpack, or in the Grunt config?

Front-end development is killing me.

Comment: I'm in the same train. The scattered documentation is killing me. This is my config http://dpaste.com/3NBJE8E, maybe it helps. Notice that I skip webpack config altogether and just set the `Gruntfile.js`

Comment: I don't know that there are any best practices, but I prefer to do as much in Webpack as possible if I'm using it. I guess my answer would be "be consistent". Either use Webpack to its full capability and do as much there as possible, or do a minimal amount of work in Webpack and focus on Grunt. Don't scatter it in both places. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also struggled with this a while ago, but managed to find a working solution for me and my team.

> Should one configure Babel in Webpack, or in the Grunt config?

Well that's completely up to, but whatever you decide: stick to it. Don't configure something there and another tool elsewhere. Do it either completely in Webpack or Grunt.

As all my projects configuration is done in the `Gruntfile.js` anyway, I found it convenient to define Babel *(or all my plugins in general)* there as well. **Splitting it up in several files is just confusing**.

In case anyone might try another workflow with [**`grunt-browserify`**](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify) using Babel and Grunt, I wrote a little [ES6 boilerplate](https://github.com/morkro/FrontBook) in how to setup a proper project.